# Horizontal scroll table row independent of other rows

Tags: html, css

My page has a fixed header, a fixed right sidebar, and an HTML table with each column having a set width (so that the table stays left of the sidebar). The table scrolls vertically, while the rest of the page remains fixed.

Each row has an expand button, which shows another row under it, with a bunch of images. This row may get very long, so the overflow needs to be hidden behind the side bar (already doing that). However, since I changed to the fixed sidebar paradigm, I am unable to scroll the row to the right without moving the whole table with it.

I will try to create a JSFiddle, but my app is an Ember/Bootstrap app, so may take a while to reconstruct in JSFiddle format. If you know the answer off-hand, please let me know.

Comment: Rather try to create a snippet in the question. Linking to outside sources is not preferred. You can use a CDN normally to include bootstrap.